# Memory warning when saving image sequence

Tags: cocoa, memory, video, warnings, frame

I am attempting to convert a video to a sequence of image frames and save them to file. However after about 5 frames I get a memory warning and the application quits due to memory pressure soon after. The images are around 10kb in size. My code is below, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Ben.

```
-(void)framesFromVideo:(AVURLAsset *)asset{
    NSArray *times = [self timeSequenceFromAsset:asset];

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *folderPath = rootPath;

    __block int i=0;
    generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeCleanAperture;
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = TRUE;
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){

        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSString *imgPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]];
            [self writeImageRef:im toPath:imgPath];
        }else if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed){
            NSLog(@"Frame generation failed with error:%@", error);
        }else if (result == AVAssetReaderStatusCancelled){
            NSLog(@"Frame generation cancelled");
        }
        NSLog(@"Completed frame");
        i++;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this>?

Comment: This was a while ago so its hard to recall what I did but I have marked the answer as accepted so i presume I followed that. I hope you solve it for yourself

Comment: Yep..  turns out generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes is not that memory efficient. So In my case, I got it working with `CVSampleBuffer`. I was able to fetch the frames rather than the actual video recording. Moulded the frames for my purpose and then made video from them. Appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this problem in a similar implementation but I was not using a completion block.
To resolve my "memory pressure", I had to release the CGImageRef.

try adding ...

```
CFRelease(im);
```

so ...

```
-(void)framesFromVideo:(AVURLAsset *)asset{
    NSArray *times = [self timeSequenceFromAsset:asset];

    NSString *rootPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *folderPath = rootPath;

    __block int i=0;
    generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.apertureMode = AVAssetImageGeneratorApertureModeCleanAperture;
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = TRUE;
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    generator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
    [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){

        if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
            NSString *imgPath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", i]];
            [self writeImageRef:im toPath:imgPath];
            CFRelease(im);
        }else if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorFailed){
            NSLog(@"Frame generation failed with error:%@", error);
        }else if (result == AVAssetReaderStatusCancelled){
            NSLog(@"Frame generation cancelled");
        }
        NSLog(@"Completed frame");
        i++;
    }];
}
```